# How should one design their students' take-home exam and decide on its length?

Tags: mathematics, exams

What strategies have you used to determine the length of your students' take home exams in the past? What is the best way to estimate/anticipate how long it will take students to complete a problem? In case it's helpful in tailoring a response, the class in question is an upper-year honours numerical analysis course covering a breadth of topics (proof comprehension+writing aptitude is expected of students), and the take-home exam is 3 days long.

Comment: 3 days long!!?? Do you actually expect them to spend the better part of 3 days working on this, or is it just a more reasonable amount of work (several hours worth) that they can do at their leisure anytime during the 3 day window?

Comment: @cag51, unlikely. Just three days until it is due.

Comment: My thinking is that students will spend time on the first day thinking about the problems, time on the second day writing solutions/responses/numerics, and have a third day "just in case". Maybe it takes them ≤ 10 hours in total, which is about twice as long as one might spend on a typical assignment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of experience then you can gauge it pretty well. Until then it is just a guess. I'd aim for about three hours of work to capture whatever the student can do if they work diligently. You might want to make it a bit longer or not, but they will have other tasks for other courses, even other exams.

But you can compensate for missing the extent and level of your questions with a couple of tricks. But you need to convince them to go along with your instructions. Tell them that even if they can't completely solve any of the problems that they should show you their work and even tell you what they tried that didn't work. From that you can get a pretty good idea of their level of knowledge.

The second trick is not to grade too "finely" While you may have some "number of points" for each problem, don't make the distinctions between "earned grades" such as A, B, ... too strict.

One of the things that an exam can do is tell the instructor how effective they are. So, it may be that if you miss the mark, that few will be able to come up with satisfactory answers. But if you've taught well, the students should have some reasonable approaches that you can judge if they "show their work."

Give them feedback on their attempts, especially if unsuccessful. Rather than give them the correct answers, point them to where they should look to develop them on their own. You can even hold a "retrospective" on some of the problems during a class period.

One of my tricks was to put one very hard problem on every exam, but tell them in advance that it was going to happen.

Another possible trick is to have a large(ish) number of questions and you indicate in some way which are easy and which are difficult, perhaps just by the ordering on the exam and perhaps with the points assigned to each. But, a few confidence builder questions on an exam can be helpful.

---

Not exactly related, but it is useful to tell them to read the exam questions immediately on receiving them and then making a serious attempt a bit later. Let the mind work for a while.

And, of course, be very clear on what resources are allowed and which are not.